# Why I can't get javascript values into my php5 code?

Tags: javascript, php, php-5.2

I have this code:

```
<?php       $html=file_get_contents('testmaker_html.html');
        echo $html;
?>



<script type="text/javascript">


    document.getElementById('save_finaly_TEST').addEventListener("click", function(){
        cover = document.getElementById('cover').value;
        keywords = document.getElementById('keywords').value.split(",");

        notificationAboutElement = "Ok!";
        notifyMe(notificationAboutElement);
      html_saver();

    <?php $test_html = "<script>document.write(html)</script>"?>   


    }); 

</script>
<?php 
        $new_test = rand().".html";
        $myfile = fopen($new_test, "w") or die("Unable to create file!");
        write($myfile, $test_html)  or die("Can't write to file");
        fclose($myfile)  or die("Can't close the file!");
        echo $new_test;
?>


<script type="text/javascript">
    console.log("$test_html: " + <?php echo $test_html; ?>);
    console.log("$new_test: " + <?php echo $new_test; ?>);
</script>
```

Why is  `$test_html` empty? I know the php and javascript is not on same server but this methodd to get values many times worked for many people. Than what can be wrong with this?

Comment: PHP and JS run at different times. You need to rethink this.

Comment: I can't see this having worked for anyone. The JS isn't run until it's sent to the client. It's just meaningless text to PHP.

Comment: You had the factory (server/PHP) build you a car, and ship it to your door. Now in your driveway (client) you put a red sticker on the wind shield ... and expect the factory to automatically know about this? No, of course that does not work. You would need to _send_ this information to the factory - and that means, you need to make a new HTTP request, either directly (submitting a form, loading a new page with URL parameters), or in the background via AJAX.

Comment: Than this is working because the php runs first? : `<script>
  var jsvar = <?php echo json_encode($PHPVar); ?>;
</script>`

Comment: @KronologiaitVme The PHP part of that will run, and it will echo the Javascript code, but the Javascript won't actually run until it's already been sent to the client.

Answer (score 0):

PHP runs on the server, and Javascript runs on the client. So when the Javascript is running, PHP has already ran.

```
<?php 
    $new_test = rand().".html";
    $myfile = fopen($new_test, "w") or die("Unable to create file!");
    fwrite($myfile, $test_html)  or die("Can't write to file");
    fclose($myfile)  or die("Can't close the file!");
    echo $new_test;
?>
<script>
    var new_test = "<?php echo $new_test; ?>";

    console.log("$new_test: " + new_test);
</script>
```

Here you're taking the file's contents, and JSON encoding it so that it is sent to the client as a valid Javascript object. Look a `view source` to see what I mean.

For other situations:

- Create a POST API if you want the client to submit things to the server
- Use Javascript if you just want to display things from Javascript on the page

Answer (score 0):

try this

you have to use `fwrite` not `write` only for file write

```
<?php       
        $html=file_get_contents('testmaker_html.html');
        echo $html;
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById('save_finaly_TEST').addEventListener("click", function(){
        cover = document.getElementById('cover').value;
        keywords = document.getElementById('keywords').value.split(",");

        notificationAboutElement = "Ok!";
        notifyMe(notificationAboutElement);
      html_saver();

    <?php $test_html = "<script>document.write(html)</script>"?>   
    }); 
</script>
<?php 
        $new_test = rand().".html";
        $myfile = fopen($new_test, "w") or die("Unable to create file!");
        fwrite($myfile, $test_html)  or die("Can't write to file");
        fclose($myfile)  or die("Can't close the file!");
        echo $new_test;
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    console.log("$test_html: " + <?php echo $test_html; ?>);
    console.log("$new_test: " + <?php echo $new_test; ?>);
</script>
```

Comment: This won't work, as $new_test won't be quoted

Comment: Thanks! I tried this but in inside the `$new_test` file will be only the `<script>document.write(html)</script>` How can I put into `$test_html` the value of `html` js variable?

Comment: so what you  want to do explain brief

Comment: I have a `html` variable in js and I want to create a file with php inside the file with this `html` variable. How can I do it?